# Does string theory require continuous spacetime?

Tags: spacetime, string-theory, discrete

Is spacetime continuous according to string theory? Or is spacetime discrete or has some type of foam?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, space time is continuous in [string theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory); the (x,y,z,t) , of the theory map one to one with the field of real numbers. The same is true for all its [extra dimensions.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory#Extra_dimensions)